# Crystal Reports 2016 - Suppressing Duplicates but keeping the most current chronological entry

Tags: duplicates, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report that details the current balance of a customer's account.  When I query the database for the account number and transactions though, it pulls in all of the customers payments.  How do I have it suppress everything but the most current transaction (or simply pull in the balance if no payment has been made yet)?

Thank you for the assistance!

Sadly, I don't know where to start formula wise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating two helper views on the database side: **Total Customer Charges** (Join Customer to the Charge Transaction, Group by Customer, Sum the charges. And **Total Customer Payments** (same logic but with Payments rather than charges).

You can then use an **outer join** between the ***Total_Customer_Charges*** and ***Total_Customer_Payments*** to easily generate your report.

Comment: Thank you for the answer here.  I am not that proficient yet to know the difference between inner/outer joining but I was able to solve my problem by removing the table that had all of the duplicates and generating a balance with a simple arithmetic addition formula.